# Multiple pages in blackberry webworks app

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I am creating an HTML5 app for a blackberry playbook.  I am wondering how to manage navigation and multiple pages.

My app is a table view, which will allow you to click a table row to load a new page, then on that page you can load a 3rd page. I don't expect to need any more than 3 layers.

How is it best to do this? Do I link to a new page as if it were a normal browser and pass the row id in the GET string to be pulled out by the JS on the child page? Or do I load the contents in a div off the page, and slide it in a bit like jquery mobile works?

I do have ajax on all pages to load the content, as everything is fetched from an API on my server. I can of course use local data storage if required, but it would be far better if there was a layering the views and pushing them on and off a stack.

I am looking for advice on how to approach a webworks app that has multiple content views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no need for manipulation of data && just want to display just keep it in single web page. But if you have considerable amount of data & you have to manipulate it then think about splitting it into another page. I faced an issue when I split my app into multiple pages. In between navigation there is lag during the page load. Even if the pages serves from local.